# Removing all duplicate entries in a field

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file that is of the following format:

```
text   number   number   A;A;A;A;A;A
text   number   number   B
text   number   number   C;C;C;C;D;C;C;C;C
```

What I want to do is remove all repeats of the entries in the fourth column to end up with this:

```
text   number   number   A
text   number   number   B
text   number   number   C;D
```

I'd prefer to use bash scripting for a solution to fit into a pipe with other text manipulation I'm doing to this file.

Thanks!

Comment: and what have your tried? Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can achieve this using `awk`. Split field 4 into an array using ; first

```
awk '{delete z; d=""; split($4,arr,";");for (k in arr) z[arr[k]]=k; for (l in z) d=d";"l; print($1,$2,$3,substr(d, 2))}' file_name
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked perfectly. I was trying some array stuff in awk, but didn't come anywhere close to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*\s/&\n/;h;s/.*\n//;:a;s/\(\([^;]\).*\);\2/\1/;ta;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Comment: This yields some odd results:

`text    number  number  A;A;A;A;A;A
text    number  number  A
text    number  number  B
text    number  number  B
text    number  number  C;C;C;C;D;C;C;C;C
text    number  number  C;D`

Comment: @JoshuaA maybe the file is tab separated not space, I'll amend the solution to cater for both.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming tab-delimited input, you could do it like this with GNU parallel:

```
parallel -C '\t' c4='$(echo {4} | tr ";" "\n" | sort -u | head -c-1 | tr "\n" ";");' \
                 echo -e '"{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t$c4"' :::: infile
```

Output:

```
text    number  number  A
text    number  number  B
text    number  number  C;D
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work too

```
awk -F";" '{
              delete words
              match($1,/[[:alpha:]]$/)
              words[substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
              printf "%s",$1
              for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){
                if (!words[$i]++) printf ";%s",$i
              }
              printf "\n"
           }' file
```

Notes:

1. Since `;` is used as field separator, it doesn't matter how many columns (or which delimiters are used for those columns) before `A;A;A;A;A;A`
2. `/[[:alpha:]]$/` can be replaced with `/[^[:space:]]+$/` to match multiple non-space characters instead of a single alphabet.
3. `if (!words[$i]++) printf ";%s",$i` prints the column/character if it doesn't exist as a key for the associative array `words`, i.e. if `words[$i]` is 0.